# Photo not uploading to backend

Tags: node.js, api, angular

I have created the back-end to get the file using the post method it's working on Postman.

but from angular2 front-end it's not working this is the service code I have done.

`data1` is the image data

```
addData(postData: Image, data1:any): Observable<Team[]> {
    console.log("team service");   
        this.image= postData;
        let body = this.image;


        let headers2= new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });


        return this.http.post(this.actionUrl, data1, options)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);       
    }
```

it's giving error:

> POST http://localhost:8080/user/45646/userName/userPhoto 500 (Internal
>   Server Error) 500 - Internal Server Error

Answer (score 1):

This is the way i use to post my data via RestAPI and it's working...

Wish below sample code is helpful for you..

```
private httpCreate(data: T): Promise<T> {
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    return this.http.post(this.getUrl(), JSON.stringify(data), {headers: headers}).toPromise().then(res => res.json()).catch(this.handleError)
}
```

Comment: It works for json data. I want to pass a file using 'form-data' content-type